# How to say if an entity is a property or a resource?

Tags: database, mongodb, structure

We cannot decide what is the best solution.

We have a collection of call centers containing several properties:

```
    {
        "blabla": 0.0,
        "_id": "543d2a1f2c6d7a0e89f2eb77",
        "balbla_foo": "543d2a1f2c6d7a0e89f2eab2",
        "blabla_bar": {},
         peek: {
            a: "boo",
        },
        bla: {
            bla: "+33891111111",
        },
    }
```

We have to add groups which are in a tree.

```
 "groups": {
            "1": {
                "label": "Branch 1",
                "children": ["2", "3"]
            },
            "2": {
                "label": "Branch 2",
                "children": []
            },
            "3": {
                "label": "Branch 3",
                "children": []
            }
 }
```

We debated where should it be. So, some think it is a property of the call center because it is a one-to-one relation.
Others think it is a resource so it has to be separated from the call center.

What is the best structure?

Thanks for your help.

EDIT:

What is the most coherent structure ?

Comment: "What is the best structure?" - none. Both have pros and cons. You'll have to fight it out :)

Comment: According to you, what would you do? @SergioTulentsev

Comment: As I said, to find out which one of them is better for your app, you need to evaluate them in the context of your app and its requirements. Which is not something I am able (or willing) to do in this short Q/A thread.